# Complex update statement

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a locations table (its_locations) with the following columns:

```
its_locations.state_tag (FK),   
its_locations.state_tag_temp (empty)
```

There is another table, its_equipment, which has these columns:

```
Its_equipment.its_equipment_id (PK),  
its_equipment.state_tag (contains the tag number of the equipment)
```

I need to copy the corresponding `its_equipment.state_tag` number over to the `its_locations.state_tag_temp` column.

I’ve tried the following (as well as other ideas) with no success and get an error

> Not unique table/alias: “its_equipment”.

I realize it has something to do with referencing the same table twice and I’ve tried different alias’ but with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
update its_locations
set its_locations.state_tag_temp = 
    (SELECT its_equipment.state_tag
    FROM its_equipment)

where its_locations.state_tag = 
    (SELECT its_equip_id
    FROM its_equipment
    join its_equipment
    on its_locations.state_tag = its_equipment.its_equip_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I made this too complicated. Here is the code that accomplished what I wanted.

```
update its_locations
set state_tag_temp = 
    (select its_equipment.state_tag
    from its_equipment
    where its_locations.state_tag = its_equipment.its_equip_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second sub select is referencing the same table, but you want to reference back to the its_locations table. You have FROM its_equipment JOIN its_locations, what you want is FROM its_equipment JOIN its_locations.

```
update its_locations
set its_locations.state_tag_temp = 
(SELECT its_equipment.state_tag
FROM its_equipment)

where its_locations.state_tag = 
(SELECT its_equip_id
FROM its_equipment its1
join its_locations its2
on its2.state_tag = its_equipment.its_equip_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the code and got the following: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'its_equipment.its_equip_id' in 'on clause'". I then tried its1.its_equip_id and got the following: "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'its_locations' for update in FROM clause"